# Accessing *Resources.groovy modules via groovy file

Tags: grails, groovy

The system I maintain is using cached-resources plugin, therefore all of the css/js files are described in *Resources.groovy (* stands for my project's name) file.

The usage is normally via *.gsp files, when including resources.

Though, I need to get the list of all files described in there via *.groovy file.

The format of *Resources.groovy file is like this:

```
modules = {
    css {
        resource url: 'fileName1.js'
        resource url: 'fileName1.js'
        ...
        resource url: 'fileNameN.js'
    }
}
```

How do I get, e.g. "fileName1.js" from service?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?  Given it a quick go in the console for Grails 2.3.4 and it seems to for me, but YMMV:

```
List urls = grailsApplication.mainContext
                             .getBean('resourceService') // Instance of [1]
                             .getModule( 'css' )         // Instance of [2]
                             .resources                  // List of [3]
                             .sourceUrl
```

1. [ResourceProcessor](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceProcessor.groovy)
2. [ResourceModule](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceModule.groovy)
3. [ResourceMeta](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceMeta.groovy)